# Why do I get this output with this recursive function?

Tags: python

```
def test(n):
    if n == 0:
        return
    print("This should print n times")
    test(n - 1)

    print("This should not print")


test(2)
```

Output:

```
This should print n times
This should print n times
This should not print
This should not print
```

Why does `This should not print` get printed out, when the function calls itself (recurses)? Isn't it supposed to start again back at the top?

Comment: first time yes, but after that you return from the recursive call and you reach the last `print`

Comment: Because recursion only suspends further execution until the called function finishes. Make it `return test(n-1)` if you don't want the "This should not print".

Comment: http://pythontutor.com/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are partially correct. When a function is called it is run from the top to the end or is told to stop (e.g. return). After the function has run, the program continues from the line it called the function at. E.g.

```
>>> def myFunc():
    print("This function is running")


>>> def OtherFunc():
    myFunc()
    print("The other function has finished running")

>>> OtherFunc()
This function is running
The other function has finished running
```

What you expected to happen was for the function call to act as the return keyword, to immediately end a function. Your program acted like this, however (with n subbed with the actual number):

```
def test(2):
    if 2 == 0:
        return
    print("This should print n times")
    test(2 - 1) #The program is told to run the function again

def test(1):
        if 1 == 0:
            return
        print("This should print n times")
        test(1 - 1) #The program is told to run the function again

def test(0):
            if 0 == 0:
                return #This exits the function, and returns to the function that called it, test(1)

print("This should not print") #This is the only line left in test(1), so it runs, and the returns to test(2), which called test(1)

print("This should not print") #This is the only line left in test(2), so it is run. The program ends as there are no more lines of code after when you called test(2)
```

So calling the function does not end the current running of a function, which will run after the function it calls has finished.

This code will do what you want:

```
def test(n):
    if n == 0:
        return
    print("This should print n times")
    test(n - 1)

    return #This will exit the function

    print("This should not print")


test(2)
```

I hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

The unwanted print will be executed as soon test(n-1) reach its internal return. The return exits just the current function call, continuing at the following line of where it was called. It doen't clear the entire stack.

Answer (score 0):

Welllll mostly. The part you're getting tripped up on is when you say "start over." The function isn't starting over -- it's calling *itself*. This will be easier to see in a pure function -- look at addition.

```
def add(x, y):
    if y == 0:
        return x
    return 1 + add(x, y-1)
```

This will add two numbers together basically by counting them (this is a terrible idea, but for illustrative purposes...) let's track this through some calls.

```
>>> add(100, 4) = 1 + add(100, 3)
    # because we're returning 1 + add(x, y-1)
... add(100, 3) = 1 + add(100, 2)
... add(100, 2) = 1 + add(100, 1)
... add(100, 1) = 1 + add(100, 0)
... add(100, 0) = 100  # this is called the base case.
```

However the answer is not `100`, as it would be if your function just started over. Each of the calls to `add` resolve to their value which plugs back into the original run of the function, so you've got:

```
>>> add(100, 4) = 1 + (1 + add(100, 2))  # subbing out...add(100, 3)
                = 1 + (1 + (1 + add(100, 1)))  # ... add(100, 2)
                = 1 + (1 + (1 + (1 + add(100, 0))))  # ... add(100, 1)
                = 1 + (1 + (1 + (1 + 100)))  # ... add(100, 0)
                = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 100  # because addition is associative
                = 104
```

---

With the examples out of the way, we can see how that applies to your function. The `return` in the conditional works perfectly, but only kicks out of the innermost function.

```
# where a = "This should print n times"
#   and b = "This should not print"
>>> test(2) = print(a); test(1); print(b)
... test(1) = print(a); test(0); print(b)
... test(0) = None  # because of the early-exit
```

Pop all those things in and you've got:

```
>>> test(2) = print(a); (print(a); None; print(b)); print(b)
#            test(1) ---^
#            test(0)---------------^
```

Which has 2 `print(a)`s and 2 `print(b)`s.